# Creating chunks of a text file using windows commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, split, chunks

I have a text file which contains a format of data as shown below example.

test.txt

```
 ABCDEFG.file1
 1239 1240 1242 1391 1392 1394 1486 1487 1489 1600
 3481 3482 3484 3633 3634 3636 3690 3691 3693 3766
 3767 3769 4526 4527 4529 4583 4584 4586 4773 4774
 4776 5153 5154 5156 5628 5629 5631

 ABCDEFG.file2
 1239 1240 1242 1391 1392 1394 1486 1487 1489 1600
 1601 1603 1657 1658 1660 2075 2076 2078 2322 2323
 2325 2740 2741 274................

 ABCDEFG.fileN
 ery 1240 1242 dfhdfh 1392 dfhdfh 1486 dfhdfh dfhdfh 1600
 1601 dfh 1657 1658 1660 2075 2076 2078 2322 2323
 2325 2740 dfhdfh 2743 dfhdfh 3083 3085 3291 3292 3294
 3481 3482 3484 3690 3691 3693 3766 3767 3769 4241
 4242 4244 4526 4527 4529 4583 4584 4586 dfhfh 4774
 4776 5153 5154 5156 54...............
```

How to split the above text file based on string "ABCDEFG". and output should be like below in different files.

file1.txt

```
   ABCDEFG.file1
   1239 1240 1242 1391 1392 1394 1486 1487 1489 1600
   3481 3482 3484 3633 3634 3636 3690 3691 3693 3766
   3767 3769 4526 4527 4529 4583 4584 4586 4773 4774
   4776 5153 5154 5156 5628 5629 5631.......
```

file2.txt

```
     ABCDEFG.file2
     1239 1240 1242 1391 1392 1394 1486 1487 1489 1600
     1601 1603 1657 1658 1660 2075 2076 2078 2322 2323
     2325 2740 2741 274................
```

and so on.. 
I need to run in windows system. Because path of the source file is fixed.
Can suggest any commands which i can execute as a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation to split the ABCDEFG string and search for it. Based on your sample data, this is going to create file1.txt, file2.txt, and fileN.txt.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in (data.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
    set first7=!line:~0,7!
    set last5=!line:~8!

    if [!first7!]==[ABCDEFG] (
        set filename=!last5!.txt
        echo ABCDEFG.!last5!>!filename!
    ) else (
        echo %%A>>!filename!
    )
)
```